# how do I scrape html after choosing an option

Tags: python, scrape

lets say I have this html -

```
<select name='h-' class='hello'
<option selected='selected' value='1'>a</option>
<option value='2'>b</option>
<option value='3'>c</option>
</select>
```

every time I choose an option the page html content changes
how do I scrape only the changed website

example -  amazon = [https://www.amazon.com/SanDisk-128GB-Extreme-microSD-Adapter/dp/B07FCMKK5X/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FCMKK5X)?

notice everytime you change the amount you wanna buy the text changes

I want to get only the text when the dropdown is set on 2

*please explain using both the first and the second examples because the amazon one is a bit different

*I am using beutifulsoup for scraping websites

Comment: I believe you're using selenium and BeautifulSoup, right?

Comment: Yea i am using both